# Need a rule that searches for * in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, rules

I need a simple rule that checks if a cell contains the char *. If i put * in the rule, it matches the entire string so i figured * is a wildcard. Is it possible to make it search for the char *? I tried escaping it like '*', "*" or *.

What I want is `text` not being shown but `text*` should be noticed by the rule.

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To search for the cells containing the wildcard character (*), use a tilde before it inside the search box:

```
~*
```

Now Excel will show you only the cells that contain the wildcard character (*).